# 是 assessing an overall situation

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage, difference, sentence-structure

This is the title of a paragraph in the book "Chinese: A Comprehensive Grammar", by Yip Po-Ching and Don Rimmington, whose content I find really hard to understand. The explanation:

> 是 shì may also be used loosely to refer to or to make an overall assessment
> of a situation, rather like its function as a marker of emphasis.

And then some examples:

> 她是不会来了。
> I don't think she will come./She is unlikely to come.
> 如今是什么办法都试过了
> So far we have tried whatever methods we could think of.

I cannot understand what the explanation is supposed to mean. The paragraph before this one explains how to use the "是…的" construction to emphasize, so I also cannot understand the difference between these two patterns, and if the omission of 是 in the example sentences changes the meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 她是不会来了。

> 如今是什么办法都试过了

What your quoted explanation means is 是 is used for an ***assessment***. E.g. 她是不会来了 // the speaker ***estimates*** that she wouldn't come. Just like to say *judging from current situation, she wouldn't come*.

Compared with 是...的, 她是不会来的 is more of ***emphasis***. The speaker is more certain that she wouldn't come. The sentence is saying that *it's impossible she would come*.

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. So, in case I omit the 是 in the above examples, the sentences are just stating a fact: 她不会来了。= She won't come (A fact; we know it because she told us); 如今什么办法都试过了 = So far we have tried every method possible (There is a limited set of methods available to use and we have tried them all). Is it correct?

Comment: @Jon Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2):

You shall learn how to detect an omitted phrase in a Chinese sentence, and separate a long sentence into meaningful pieces (like clues of a puzzle). For the two cases:

她是不会来了。Actually, the complete sentence should be 我"想(猜,估計)"她是不会来了。 I think (guess, estimate) she won't come.

如今是什么办法都试过了。 = 如今是 什么办法都试过了。如今是 is a customary phrase similar to English - "now the situation is....". There are quite a few phrases that share the same pattern:

- 現今是 = 如今是 = 現下是 = 目前是
- 前題是 Before going further, let's set some things straight. Example: "我願意和你共創事業。 前題是 你必須...."
- 問題是 Before going further, here are some questions/problems, .... "我願意和你共創事業。 前題是 你父母許可嗎? 你有獨立的經濟來源嗎?...."